# Seat Leon 1.9TDI 81KW 2002 Brake pedal goes to floor

Tags: brakes, seat-leon

I recently had my brakes have full service. They were taken off. Taken apart, cleaned and added new grease. Swapped brake fluid. After that, the brake pedal started to go to floor. I can pump it up, but when I apply even pressure it slowly goes to floor. Before service I had to press very little for the brakes to engage, and it didn't go to the floor.

There are no visible leaks, so first idea was master cylinder. So I replace it, still nothing. Diagnostic said that there is a small vacuum leak, but everything is within the norms and the leak was already there before the full service.

Both times brakes were bleed.

During the service one of the brake cylinders were stuck, and there were signs that there might have been large heat at some point. The old brake pad literally crumbled away when taking off.

Out of all the thing that has been done to the breaks there are currently 3 possible culprits:

1. The vacuum leak
2. The brake booster
3. The brake caliper that was stuck

Any more suggestions what might cause a soft brake pedal and the pedal going to floor when held under pressure?

GIven that the brake fluid was completely removed and new added, does that mean that maybe they need more bleeding?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!